# Returning nullable string types

Tags: c#, string, nullable

So I have something like this

```
public string? SessionValue(string key)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session[key].ToString() == null || HttpContext.Current.Session[key].ToString() == "")
        return null;

    return HttpContext.Current.Session[key].ToString();
}
```

which doesn't compile.

How do I return a nullable string type?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

String is already a nullable type.  Nullable can only be used on ValueTypes.  String is a reference type.

Just get rid of the "?" and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 7):

As everyone else has said, `string` doesn't need `?` (which is a shortcut for `Nullable<string>`) because all reference types (`class`es) are already nullable. It only applies to value type (`struct`s).

Apart from that, you should not call `ToString()` on the session value before you check if it is `null` (or you can get a `NullReferenceException`). Also, you shouldn't have to check the result of `ToString()` for `null` because it should never return `null` (if correctly implemented). And are you sure you want to return `null` if the session value is an empty `string` (`""`)?

This is equivalent to what you meant to write:

```
public string SessionValue(string key)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session[key] == null)
        return null;

    string result = HttpContext.Current.Session[key].ToString();
    return (result == "") ? null : result;
}
```

Although I would write it like this (return empty `string` if that's what the session value contains):

```
public string SessionValue(string key)
{
    object value = HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
    return (value == null) ? null : value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: "because all reference types (classes) are already nullable." --> Does not appear to be so. `public class vector { public static vector func() { return null; } }` results in an error.

Comment: Interfaces seem to be nullable always

Comment: @Assimilater I just tried your code. It compiled and ran just fine for me. `vector` is a class, so `func()` can definitely return `null`.

Comment: my bad. I was bouncing between struct and class and they are different. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign null to a string since its a reference type, you don't need to be able to make it nullable.

Answer (score 0):

String is already a nullable type.  You don't need the '?'.

> Error 18  The type 'string' must be a
>   non-nullable value type in order to
>   use it as parameter 'T' in the generic
>   type or method 'System.Nullable'

Answer (score 0):

`string` is already nullable on its own.